# Codeigniter Paginantion get real result total in controller

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am doing a complex query of a large database in my model and need to count the total rows before limiting the results for paging.

My model looks as follow:

```
public function get_categoryads($limit, $start, $cid, $type)
{
$this->db->start_cache();

// All your conditions without limit
$this->db->from();
$this->db->where(); // and etc...
$this->db->stop_cache();

$total_rows = $this->db->count_all_results(); // This will get the real total rows

// Limit the rows now so to return per page result
$this->db->limit($per_page, $offset);
$result = $this->db->get();

return array(
    'total_rows' => $total_rows,
    'result'     => $result,
);
}
```

I don't understand how to now call it in my controller.
 1. Get the results to be handed to the view
 2. Get total_rows to be handed to the pagination config in the controller.
How do I call the array of results & total_rows in my controller?

In my controller:

```
// call the model function to get the result List data if not in an array
$data['results'] = $this->my_model->get_categoryads(10, 0, $cid, $type);
```

Sure this wont work as the model pushes out an array...
What should I then do in my controller to get the following:

```
// call the model function to get the result List data if not in an array
$data['results'] = $this->my_model->get_categoryads(10, 0, $cid, $type);
// Get total results for Pagination Config:
$config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all_results();
```

Do I do

```
$config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all_results($data['results']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this in controller:

```
$results = $this->my_model->get_categoryads(10, 0, $cid, $type);

// Array of result rows to be sent to view
$data['results'] = $results['result'];

// For pagination config:
$config['total_rows'] = $results['total_rows'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Sultan I now get the total rows but get an error when calling $data['results'] in the view.
foreach($results as row){} gives me an error. (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$results' (T_VARIABLE) in....) How do I now call $data['results'] in the view?

Comment: The error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$results' (T_VARIABLE) in...." comes if you have any unclosed braces. 
You have to just call $results in the view file. This should work:
foreach($results as $row)
{
   
}

Answer (score 0):

you can use codeigniter pagination concept:-

1. you have take page offset by uri segment like:-

   `$page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;`
           // it's depends on your uri segments
2. Now call your model with about page offset

   `$this->my_model->get_results($page,$something);`
3. Now count total number of rows:-

   ```
     $cnt=$this->my_model->count_results($something);
   ```

if 2nd and 3rd steps is done in one go then you have to do it like..

```
      $temp=array();
      $temp['result']=your query result;
      $temp['count']=your count result;
```

4. Now insert this lines for pagination:-

   ```
   $this->load->library("pagination");
   $config = array();

   $config["total_rows"] = $cnt; // or $result['count']
   $config["per_page"] = 10;
   $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
   $config['num_links']=2;
   $config['first_link'] = 'First';
   $config['last_link'] = 'Last';  
   $config["base_url"] = your _controller_url
   $config["display_pages"]=TRUE;
   $this->pagination->initialize($config);
   $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
   ```
5. Now call your view:-

   ```
       $this-> load->view(your_view_name);
   ```
6. In your view you have to add `div` tag like:

   ```
      <div class="pagination">
          <?php echo $links;?>
      </div>
   ```

Hope this may help you.

Comment: The issue is not how to do paging.
I am calling the result & total_rows in an array in the model. I want to know how I then call the results to send to view and ALSO what I should do to call the total_rows in the controller so I can use it for the $config['total_rows'] for pagination... Or do I misunderstand your answer?

Comment: see in my answer i have counted two things separately and if you wanna you can count it in one array and you can pass it by array. Ok i am updating my answer

Comment: I edited my question as it seems your answer do not relate to my question.

Comment: maybe i have misunderstood your query...i am sorry about that...can you tell me what exactly you want???

Comment: the answer from @Sultan was more in the line of answer I am looking for, but still have errors... I now get the total rows but get an error when calling $data['results'] in the view. foreach($results as row){} gives me an error. (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$results' (T_VARIABLE) in....) How do I now call $data['results'] in the view?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this in a better code way.

1. Grab the total results before query filter.
2. Grab the total results after query filter.
3. Grab the results after query filter.

With that said:

```
public function get_categoryads($limit, $start, $cid, $type)
{
   $this->db->select('COUNT(field) AS `total`')
            ->from('table');

   $totalRows = $this->db->get()->row()->total;

   $this->db->select('...')
            ->from('...')
            ->where('...')
            ->limit('...');

   $totalRowsAfterLimit = $this->db->get()->num_rows();
   $results             = $this->db->get()->results();

   return array('totalRows'           => $totalRows,
                'totalRowsAfterLimit' => $totalRowsAfterLimit,
                'results'             => $results);

}
```

Finally, in your controller you may do something like:

```
list($totalRows, $totalRowsAfterLimit, $results) = $this->my_model->get_categoryads('...');
```

And you are now able to loop through the results.

```
foreach($results as $result)
{
   echo $result->some_field_from_database;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample @Linesofcode I will surely test the code.
Just one question... Will this be light on a big database query?

Comment: It should be, specially because I used `COUNT` which is way faster than counting the results from the PHP array.

Comment: will one be able to use group_by() in the COUNT code or will it count the unique fields?
I know it does not work with count_all_results() and will give incorrect totals.

Comment: You are able to do the filters you want to.